# SqlCommand.Parameters.Add NOT substituting into Command Text

Tags: c#, sql

I've tried everything I can think of and this simple C# code is not working. The result is that the parameters are NOT getting substituted so the query results in no data.

```
string query = @"select TOP 20 [ID], [NAME], LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, ADDRESS, FEATURES, [DATE UPDATED],
                           ABS(ABS(LATITUDE)- @Lat1 ) + ABS(ABS(LONGITUDE)- @Lng1 ) as diff 
                           from Facility f
                           where (ABS(ABS(LATITUDE)- @Lat2 ) + ABS(ABS(LONGITUDE)- @Lng2 ) < 2)
                           order by 8";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    // Create the connectionString
    // Trusted_Connection is used to denote the connection uses Windows Authentication
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=ERICS_TOSHIBA\\WEAVSQL;Database=WellBe;Trusted_Connection=true";
    conn.Open();
    // Create the command
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    // Add the parameters.
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Lat1", SqlDbType.Float));
    command.Parameters["@Lat1"].Value = dHomeLat;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Lat2", SqlDbType.Float));
    command.Parameters["@Lat2"].Value = dHomeLat;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Lng1", SqlDbType.Float));
    command.Parameters["@Lng1"].Value = dHomeLng;
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Lng2", SqlDbType.Float));
    command.Parameters["@Lng2"].Value = dHomeLng;

    Console.WriteLine("QUERY IS: \n\n {0}", command.CommandText);
}
```

The output of this WriteLine is this:

```
select TOP 20 [ID], [NAME], LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, ADDRESS, FEATURES, [DATE UPDATED],
                           ABS(ABS(LATITUDE)- @Lat1 ) + ABS(ABS(LONGITUDE)- @Lng1 ) as diff
                           from Facility f
                           where (ABS(ABS(LATITUDE)- @Lat2 ) + ABS(ABS(LONGITUDE)- @Lng2 ) < 2)
                           order by 8
```

Why won't the parameter values substitute? I've tried about 6 different versions of the syntax. Not all the code is listed above. There are valid values for all variables including the `dHomeLat` and `dHomeLng`.

Comment: Parameters never replace the query string. It sends the actual values *separate* from it. You'll see them when running a the profiler on the server. But what you're seing is the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

Parameters aren't substituted into `CommandText`; they're sent to the server alongside the command (this enables things like query plan caching).

You don't actually have a problem.

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks.  So I guess the query results in 0 rows.  but when I run the same query in SQL Management Studio I get results.  So there must be some other issue with the query.